How to specify fontsize for individual slides MARP
I am writing my presentation using marp. Everything is cool however, I am not able to specify fontsize for individual slides. Any idea?

Every slide is wrapped in a html <section> tag and we can style it by including css at the start of the slide markdown. A bit clunky, but I haven't found a better way.
<style scoped>
section {
    font-size: 30px;
}
</style>

With scoped the styles will only apply to the current slide. If you leave scoped away the font-size will be used for every slide, see marp docs.
Complete example slide with css one-liner:
---

<style scoped>section{font-size:30px;}</style>

# Smaller heading

---

